# Creating object to represent XML data using C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

below is the XML code.

```
<Shops>
   <Shop>
      <Location>INDIA</Location>
      <Id>123</Id>
      <ShopLists>
         <ShopList>
            <Area>500sqft</Area>
            <Name>Home Decor</Name>
            <LicenseNo>Ab123</LicenseNo>
         </ShopList>
         <ShopList>
            <Area>1000sqft</Area>
            <LicenseNo>Ab123</LicenseNo>
         </ShopList>
       </ShopLists>
    </Shop>
</Shops>
```

Creating an object with C# using Linq is finding challenging here as one of the data is missing in 'shoplist' and structure is nested. reply if find some inputs on this.

Comment: [C# MSDN XML Object Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @adv12     Yes. the Shop is capitalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use XmlSerializer with objects to perform such tasks.

Reference Assembly System.Xml.Serialization

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

First create the object model:

```
    [XmlRoot("Shops")]
    public class XmlShops
    {
        [XmlElement("Shop",typeof(Shop))]
        public List<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shop
    {
        [XmlElement("Location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("ShopLists")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ShopList",typeof(ShopList))]
        public List<ShopList> ShopLists { get; set;}
    }

    public class ShopList
    {
        [XmlElement("Area")]
        public string Area { get;set; }

        [XmlElement("Home")]
        public string Home { get;set; }

        [XmlElement("LicenseNo")]
        public string LicenseNo { get;set; }
    }
```

Afterwards use the Serializer to get the xml data into the object model:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlShops));

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\tmp\test.xml"))
{
     XmlShops data = (XmlShops)ser.Deserialize(sr);
     // xml should be serialized to your object model into data.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to look at http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ put your xml and you will be able to convert your xml representation into C# classes.

you can then use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize your xml into specific type as exemplified in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope that helps.